# Two uncorrelated random variables with variances dependent on each other?

Tags: probability

Can anyone give an example of two uncorrelated random variables that have variances dependent on each other?

Comment: The two variances are just two numbers. In what sense are they supposed to be "dependent on each other" (or, much more importantly, how would they be supposed not to be "dependent on each other")?

Comment: I am reading the question as *"Can anyone give an example of two uncorrelated random variables, that have variances, dependent on each other? "* (i.e., the two r.v.'s are square integrable), @Gae.S.

Comment: @ClementC. Ah, it makes sense.